# Inheriting AppCompat 22.1.1 Dialog colorAccent from app theme doesn't work

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-styles, android-appcompat

I'm trying to set up AppCompat's Dialogs so that the buttons use the same color as the application's accent color, without repeating the color itself. This was working perfectly with AppCompat v22 (only for Lollipop, obviously) by using this styles file in `values-v21`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF9800</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

When [AppCompat v22.1 was released](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) I tried to set this up for all Android versions, so I moved these styles to the base `values` folder, and basically replaced all the `android:` and v21-specific attributes by their AppCompat counterparts.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF9800</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

However, it doesn't work -- the app **crashes** when it attempts to show an alert dialog. There are some warnings in logcat which I strongly suspect are related to the problem:

```
05-08 16:55:44.863  W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x7f01009e
```

And the exception is:

```
05-08 16:55:44.900  21301-21301/com.example.test.testaccentcolor E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.test.testaccentcolor, PID: 21301
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #124: Error inflating class Button
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:75)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:902)
            at com.example.test.testaccentcolor.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:538)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:187)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 5
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:425)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:991)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:56)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:97)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:782)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:810)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:75)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:216)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:240)
            at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:373)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
            at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:902)
            at com.example.test.testaccentcolor.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:99)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:538)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:187)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Of course, duplicating the color value (or creating a color resource and referencing it) works... but due to the project structure I need it this way.

To sum up: **I assume the reference to `?attr/colorAccent` is somehow creating a cycle... but I cannot figure out why or how to fix it.**

Any ideas?

---

**Update: Why do I need/want to set `accentColor` only in the theme?**

We have a library that is common to many applications, that defines "base" themes from which the actual application theme must be derived. So the above example, which is simplified, is actually more akin to something like this:

```
<!-- Styles that are inherited by application-generated styles. -->
<style name="Theme.Library.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Library.Dark.AlertDialog</item>
    <!-- more properties -->
</style>

<style name="Theme.Library.Dark.AlertDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <!-- more properties -->
</style>
```

(plus the corresponding variants for Light and Light with Dark Action Bar).

After this, the application project should only pick a base theme from the list provided, and then have something like:

```
<!-- Application theme -->
<style name="ApplicationTheme" parent="Theme.Library.Dark">
    <-- Ohter material colors -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF9800</item>
</style>
```

At least this is the ideal situation, which worked before (as @Vikram points out in his answer, apparently only because there are two different `colorAccent` attributes).

The advantage of this scheme is that I am not forced to provide default values for `colorAccent` in the library themes, as those are inherited from the AppCompat base ones.

Also, should I need to create color resources, I would need two of them (for light and dark variants) since the default colors are not the same.

So, ideally, I'm looking for a similar solution (provided one exists).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
```

You already know that this doesn't work. Here's why:

```
ssize_t ResTable::Theme::getAttribute(uint32_t resID, Res_value* outValue,
    uint32_t* outTypeSpecFlags) const 
{
    int cnt = 20;

    if (outTypeSpecFlags != NULL) *outTypeSpecFlags = 0;

    do {
        ....
        ....        
        if (type == Res_value::TYPE_ATTRIBUTE) {
            if (cnt > 0) {
                cnt--;
                resID = te.value.data;
                continue;
            }
            ALOGW("Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x%08x\n", resID);
            return BAD_INDEX;
        } 
        ....
        ....
    } while (true);

    return BAD_INDEX;
}
```

The snippet is self-explanatory. You can have:

```
<item name="colorZ" >?attr/colorY</item>
```

and then:

```
<item name="colorY" >?attr/colorX</item>
```

....
....

But chaining attributes like this cannot be more that 20 levels deep. Android gives up because of `Too many attribute references...`.

In your case, you are setting an attribute's value by trying to read its present value. Android goes looking, but finds another reference instead - endless pursuit.

**Why did it work before?**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF9800</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In `AppTheme`, you are setting support library's `colorAccent` attribute (no **android:** namespace). Under `AlertDialogTheme`, you set `android:colorAccent` to **support library's `colorAccent`**. This is why an endless loop does not take shape.

`?attr/colorAccent` is resolved within the `Context` you pass when creating the `AlertDialog`. For this reason, it is resolved against `<item name="colorAccent">#FF9800</item>`.

One possible workaround would be to define a custom `attr` in `res/values/attrs.xml`:

```
<attr name="alertDialogColorAccent" format="reference|color"/>
```

Now, we can initialize this attribute under `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF9800</item>
    <item name="alertDialogColorAccent" >?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

and use it in `AlertDialogTheme`:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/alertDialogColorAccent</item>
</style>
```

BUT, this will still not work. Its still creates a cycle - `colorAccent` is `alertDialogColorAccent` & `alertDialogColorAccent` is `colorAccent`. Somewhere along the chain, an actual color value needs to be set:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF9800</item>
    <item name="alertDialogColorAccent" >#FF9800</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>
```

Now, you can initialize `colorAccent` with `alertDialogColorAccent` since it refers to an actual color value:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">?attr/alertDialogColorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is _almost_ the solution I need, but not quite. I had experimented with something similar and, according to my tests, it does not work if I try to set `<item name="alertDialogColorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>` in `AppTheme`. Can you verify this? My objective is to provide a few custom themes in a library, that can be customized by only setting `colorAccent` in them.

Comment: @matiash I see. Let's talk here: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/77523/room-for-question-30132302?tab=general)

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Vikram's excellent answer, I ended up with this (I'm putting it up for future reference, in case someone is interested in the actual solution).

For the base styles file, in `values` (*note: different XML files for attributes, colors, &c are preferable -- they are all together here for compactness*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />

    <attr name="dialogColorAccent" />
    <color name="myAccentColor">#FF9800</color>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
        <item name="dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
        <item name="dialogColorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">?attr/dialogColorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">?attr/dialogColorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The new `dialogColorAccent` attribute is necessary so that it can be referenced from the dialog styles. Unfortunately it cannot reference `colorAccent` itself (and neither is the reverse possible) so both must have the same value (in this case, a reference to a color resource).

This makes sure that AlertDialogs built with `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder` use the accent color for the positive/negative buttons for all Android versions.

However, an additional file is necessary for some dialogs (such as `DatePickerDialog`, `TimePickerDialog` and `ProgressDialog`) that have material versions in Lollipop but no AppCompat equivalent so far. Hence, the following style file goes in `values-v21`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This will make these new dialogs have the accent color too (but only in Lollipop, obviously).

---

The solution might seem a little convoluted (referencing `@myAccentColor` from the `AlertDialogTheme` style is way simpler :)) but it was necessary because multiple themes are defined in a library, and the idea was that these themes can be inherited and used with minimal changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `?attr/colorAccent` here refer to the very same one you are trying to set:

```
<item name="colorAccent">?attr/colorAccent</item>
```

You can extract the accent color to a `@color` attribute, then use it for both app theme and dialog theme.

**colors.xml**

```
<color name="accent">#FF9800</color>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this is a possibility, but I was asking for other solutions. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I set `android:textColor` to `@null` in my dialog theme and it helps.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@null</item>
</style>
```

Also this `trick` help me to fix `android:textColor` problem for other buttons.

```
<style name="Button.Base.Borderless" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@null</item>
</style>
```

**some_layout.xml**

```
<Button
    style="@style/Button.Base.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hint" />
```

Now button text color is `colorAccent` defined in `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Button.Base.Borderless</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
</style>
```